# Cloth covered flexible ring or a bag clamp in a dust collector?

Tags: sawdust, dust-collection

I recently acquired a dust collector, and it came with two ways of mounting the chip collection bag, but didn't explain why I would want to use one over the other in the assembly instructions.

The two mounting options I have are a cloth covered flexible ring or a big metal bag clamp that resembles a giant hose clamp.

The flexible ring is supposed to have the top 6" of bag folded over it, and sits inside an internal groove in the dust collector and is held in by spring force and friction.

The bag clamp goes around the outside of the dust collector, with the bag in between the outer diameter and the bag clamp.

**Are there benefits and downsides to each method?** I'm wondering if it's a convenience (clamp) vs performance (flexible ring) tradeoff. Does one provide a better seal?

Make/Model is [Delta 50-767](http://www.deltamachinery.com/products/dust-management/item/50-767).

[Manual (PDF)](http://www.deltamachinery.com/downloads/manuals/dust_management/50-767/50-767%20Manual%20Rev%203.pdf) Page 13, Figures 14 and 15.

Comment: Are you sure that the bag clamp isn't for the top bag? On multiple dust collectors I've owned, from Jet and Delta, the bag clamp is for the top bag, and the cloth covered metal hoop is for the chip collection bag.

Comment: Nope, the instructions are very clear that the two options are for the chip collection bag. The filter bag has a sewn in flexible ring.

Comment: Interesting design! My only gripe with the internal / spring tension held in place ring is that it creates a ledge that collects dust-- when I go to change it, I always end up with a bit of a mess that I'd imagine an 'outside' bag would avoid.

Comment: Every time that I empty my dust collector with the bag clamp I cuss and swear aloud and wonder why it could not have been made easier to re-attach the bag.

Comment: What make / model dust collector is it? Maybe this would help get an answer.

Comment: My collector has a "cyclone" to pick up the bigger pieces in a small drum the sawdust goes into the bag. With the folded bag and spring latch on mine, The bag has lasted longer than my first system but has blown off a few times when I let the bag get over 50% full and that made a really big mess.

Comment: I'd suggest including manufacturer and model (and maybe even pictures and a link to the manual - oooohhhhh) to help people get a better idea of what's going on. This one has been languishing for a while, and even 50 points may not help without some additional details. _Um, as I just noticed @JasonC mentioned **3 months** ago..._

Comment: @FreeMan, I think I got the notification of Jason's request when I was profoundly busy, and promptly forgot all about it. Thanks for the poke, make/model added.

Comment: Also, what was Delta thinking, coming out with a model number [767](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_767#/media/File:Delta_Air_Lines_B767-332_N130DL.jpg)? Make sure you get that 50- in there!

Comment: Sorry, @Doresoom, the bolded was meant as a comment to myself repeating something that was said 3 months ago, not getting on you for it. I realize now that it didn't come out right. Also, is the next model up the 50-777? It can carry more chips over longer distances.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sent Delta an email:

> From: Jason C
>   Sent: Tuesday, March 08, 2016 8:15 PM
>   To: Customer Care <customercare@dpec-na.com>
>   Subject: 50-767 dust collection bag mounts
>
> The 50-767 offers both a cloth-covered ring and a metal clamp
>   as options for attaching the collection bag.
>
> What is the difference between these two options? Does one provide a
>   better seal? Is it a tradeoff of convenience vs. seal? Why would you
>   choose one over the other?

And they said:

> It’s just a personal preference.  You get a good seal w/either.  Our tech dept can be reached at 866-999-1499 if you have further questions.

So it doesn't seem to matter.

Now, if you look at the manual, the last step for the ring option is:

> 3. Tug slightly on the bag to eliminate any slack and to make sure that the bag is secure and will not detach during collection.

This does seem to imply that there is at least enough of a risk of the user attaching the bag incorrectly with this method to mention it in the manual. This seems to be user error, though, not attachment failure. It also seems to be a minor risk, based on the customer service reply and the fact that nobody really seems to have a strong opinion either way (lack of answers posted to this question is some example evidence here).

I hypothesize (this is just my personal opinion), that the reason both methods were provided is that both are good, and it is cheaper and easier for Delta to provide both methods and let the user choose than it is for them to potentially drive away customers that have a preference one way or the other (plus, empowering the user to make a decision, even a small one, is a nice way to improve the product image). I can certainly imagine that some folks may e.g. trust the clamp over the ring, and others may value the convenience of the ring - and regardless of whether or not either of these preferences is based in truth, by providing both, Delta doesn't have to deal with a debate.

(Or it may be an even simpler reason: Maybe in a design meeting they got into a heated debate about which one to use, until one sane hero stepped up and said "let's just use both; next discussion item please, I don't have all day".)

Comment: Don't know.  I'm not seeing any flags yet

Comment: Btw, I bet vacuum system design meetings really suck.

Comment: Oh! that leaves me gasping for air!

Comment: @JasonC Thanks for taking the initiative to email Delta. I suppose I could have done that myself to start with...but then we wouldn't have this great answer on the internet.